# Xcode 4 crashing on Run on MacOS 10.9

Tags: xcode, crash, osx-mavericks

I'm dealing with some legacy code, won't compile on anything later than SDK 10.5 due to randomly abolished APIs, so I have good reason to stick with old compilers. I've been using Xcode 4.6.3; I recently clean-installed from OS X 10.7 to 10.9.

A new problem arises: Xcode reliably crashes on the Run command. I can build my applications just fine; they run successfully if I double-click the built product. But if I try to run directly from Xcode, Xcode crashes. The nature of the app doesn't seem to matter; I have tried this both with commandline and GUI apps. Selfsame result.  Any insights?

From the crash report, in case it helps:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4H1503
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[__NSCFString alloc]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x400c22b60
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff8f224244 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x00007fff91ebae75 objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2  0x00007fff8f22712d -[NSObject(NSObject)     doesNotRecognizeSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)
  3  0x00007fff8f182272 ___forwarding___ (in CoreFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff8f181df8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 (in CoreFoundation)
  5  0x00000001107070a6 -[DBGLLDBDebugLocalService operationWorkerWithLaunchSession:error:] (in DebuggerLLDBService)
  6  0x0000000110707593 -[DBGLLDBRunLocalService operationWorkerWithLaunchSession:error:] (in DebuggerLLDBService)
  7  0x000000010b1bf8e7 -[IDERunDestination runOperationForLaunchSession:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
  8  0x000000010b1be557 -[IDELaunchSchemeAction
```